# Why is my "return" outside the function?

Tags: python

I've got a simple function here that just gives me a list of the square numbers up till a number that I choose. 3 in this example.

```
def range_squared(n):

    """Takes a non-negative integer value n and returns the list of the numbers, up to n-1 squared.
    """
a = []
for i in range(n):
    i = i ** 2    
    a.append(i)

return a

print (range_squared(3))
```

---

It's still in the loop, I think, but I don't understand why. Is it an indentation problem? I've tried putting space here and there, but with no luck. Also, I'm not sure how to get rid of the "undefined name '**n**'" in "for i in range(**n**)". Am I supposed to change it to "a"?

Comment: Year, it is an indentation problem...

Comment: Also, your function could be very short: `range_squared = lambda x: [pow(i, 2) for i in range(x)]`

Comment: Check Piotr's answer.

Comment: Ahh, I saw it, thanks. I'm new to the site, so it's a bit difficult to navigate. Thank you for your help as well.

Comment: Okay, if an answer is helpful then you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) it. The accept button is at the answer's left.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for letting me know. I've clicked the green arrow now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should look like this:

```
def range_squared(n):

    """Takes a non-negative integer value n and returns the list of the numbers, up to n-1 squared.
    """
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        i = i ** 2    
        a.append(i)

    return a

print (range_squared(3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I kept the 'n' and didn't change it and it works perfectly now!

Comment: While you answer the question about syntax formatting, I want to add a minor tidbit about the piece of code as originally written. While the docstring claims that the function takes a non-negative number, it will happily accept a negative number and the result will be an empty list.